# Error when setting backgroundColor in Jetpack Compose Card using Color.Green

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I'm encountering an issue in my Jetpack Compose code where setting the background color of a Card to `Color.Green` is resulting in an error. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```kotlin
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(200.dp)
        .height(300.dp)
        .padding(12.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(10.dp)),
    backgroundColor = Color.Green // error is showing in this code why
) {
    // Content inside the Card
}

Despite using the correct Color import (import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color), the compiler is flagging an error specifically on the backgroundColor = Color.Green line. I've ensured that the necessary dependencies are in place, and other colors from the Color class are working as expected.

Is there something specific about the Color.Green value that might be causing this error within the context of a Jetpack Compose Card? Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
```

Comment: well, what's the error ? does it compile or not ?

Comment: its showing compile error with **Cannot find a parameter with this name: backgroundColor**

Comment: There is no parameter called backgroundColor for Card composable,
instead of `backgroundColor = Color.Green` you should use colors parameter like this:

    
`colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.Green)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you imported all the compose elements? The code snippet you shared is correct, I think some import might be causing an issue.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CornerSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun App() {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(300.dp)
            .padding(12.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(10.dp)),
        backgroundColor = Color.Green,
    ) {
        // CONTENT
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked everything all ok I don't know why its not working